# Using react-native components for react web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How can we use share  components between react-native and react web projects. I have read react native can be derived from react. How is it possible to use same js code between two projects (fully or partially) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `react-native-web` library. It's pretty good:

https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

As long as you only use react native components, e.g. `View` instead of `div`, and `Text` instead of `p` etc, you'll be able to share view components between your app and website. Then you can pass down all the data from API calls etc as props from within the individual mobile app/website code.

In my projects I have a `common` folder that contains all these shared view components, and only put the platform specific code inside `mobile` or `web-app`. It works pretty well that way.